# Printing in columns Python

Tags: python, printing

I have a text file (with  tab separation)such as  :

```
Plate   Well Group Type    Sample          Wavelength Reading Abs   Meas. Time [s]
Plate 1  A05 Assay Blank   Blank_Assay 1/1 340        1       0.113 0.080         
Plate 1  A05 Assay Blank   Blank_Assay 1/1 340        2       0.114 3.660         
Plate 1  A05 Assay Blank   Blank_Assay 1/1 340        3       0.114 7.230         
Plate 1  A01 Assay Control Ctrl_0001 1/1   340        1       0.706 0.000         
Plate 1  A01 Assay Control Ctrl_0001 1/1   340        2       0.706 3.580           
Plate 1  A01 Assay Control Ctrl_0001 1/1   340        54      0.685 189.740       
Plate 1  B01 Assay Control Ctrl_0002 1/1   340        4       0.698 11.220
```

And so on.

I split it with `\t` separator and  access all the individual columns.

I  want it to just give me

```
               A05               A01        B01
Time(S)        Abs               Abs        Abs
0
```

I want time Time(s) to be sorted in chronological order from 0 -> highest number and at each respective time, the corresponding absorbance reading to be added to the respective column (with the header).

I want that final output to be outputted to a new file.

Comment: It might be difficult to sort on `Time(s)` because that column appears to be empty. Or have the edits affected the data?

Comment: @mhawke The  last column (Measur.Time(s) just  looks misaligned. But its  the last column).

Comment: @LearningNeverStops : I have basically got  to the stage, where I split   all the values of "Well" column into  a sorted set(list). Then I use that  list in a for loop, looping over all the lines of the file and searching the well column, and printing out the Abs, whenever  the header is the same. And just printing a blank space whenever the header is not the same. So, I get the right result, but after jumping to the next item in the first header list, it continues to print on new lines, instead of printing in columns. And that's where I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

data = np.genfromtxt("values.csv",delimiter=' ',skip_header=1,dtype=None)

dataDict = {}
for i,dat in enumerate(data):
    dataDict[dat[10]]=[dat[2],dat[9]]

orderedDict = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dataDict.items()))

fp = open("outResult.csv",'wb')
fp.write(" \tA05\tA01\tB01\n")
fp.write("Time(S)\tAbs\tAbs\tAbs\n")
print " \tA05\tA01\tB01"
print "Time(S)\tAbs\tAbs\tAbs"
for key in orderedDict.keys():
    str1 = ''
    str2 = ''
    str3 = ''
    if orderedDict[key][0] == 'A01':
        str1 = orderedDict[key][1]
        str2 = ' '
        str3 = ' '
    elif orderedDict[key][0] == 'A05':
        str1 = ' '
        str2 = orderedDict[key][1]
        str3 = ' '
    else:
        str1 = ' '
        str2 = ' '
        str3 = orderedDict[key][1]
    fp.write("%.02f\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(key,str1,str2,str3))
    print "%.02f\t%s\t%s\t%s"%(key,str1,str2,str3)
fp.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused on many levels though, as I am still learning. I have both collections and numpy. Firstly, I notice you manually write fp.write(" \tA05\tA01\tB01\n"). Is it not possible to add the headers automatically at the start, on top, instead of manually specifying it? Also, I get an error at "fp.write("%.02f\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(key,str1,str2,str3))" 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
    fp.write("%.02f\t%s\t%s\t%s\n"%(key,str1,str2,str3))
TypeError: float argument required, not str" `

Comment: It is possible to automate the header line, in case there are different headers. The error you get should be solved by replacing `key` by `float(key)` on that line. But I wonder why the key is read as a string. Otherwise to find the issue you could replace `%.02f` by `%s`. This plots the string value.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I want time Time(s) to be sorted in chronological order from 0 ->
>   highest number and at each respective time, the corresponding
>   absorbance reading to be added to the respective column (with the
>   header).

Looking at the complete data that you originally posted with your question (before it was truncated by an editor), you are not going to be able to match abs readings based on the `Meas. Time [s]` column because this is not the same across each reading for A05, A01, and B01. Instead, (I think?) the `Reading` number column is the way to join the respective readings because `Meas. Time [s]` is similar for each reading number, for all wells.

So, using the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module, read the file and group the data by the `Reading` column. Then iterate over the grouped readings in order, grabbing the value of the `Abs` for each `Well`. The grouping is done using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of dicts.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# CSV column numbers
WELL_COL = 1
READING_COL = 6
ABS_COL = 7

with open('readings') as infile:
    data = defaultdict(dict)
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    _ = next(reader)    # skip the header line
    for row in reader:
        data[int(row[READING_COL])][row[WELL_COL]] = row[ABS_COL]

outfile_fmt = '{:<10}{:<10}{:<10}{}\n'    # N.B. new line suitable for file.write(), not print()

with open('abs_readings', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(outfile_fmt.format('', 'A05', 'A01', 'B01'))
    outfile.write(outfile_fmt.format('Reading', 'Abs', 'Abs', 'Abs'))
    for reading, abs in sorted(data.items()):
        outfile.write(outfile_fmt.format(reading, abs['A05'], abs['A01'], abs['B01']))
```

After reading in the data from the CSV file, `data` looks like this:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(data.items())
[(1, {'A01': '0.706', 'A05': '0.113', 'B01': '0.698'}),
 (2, {'A01': '0.706', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.698'}),
 (3, {'A01': '0.705', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.698'}),
 (4, {'A01': '0.705', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.698'}),
 (5, {'A01': '0.705', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.698'}),
 (6, {'A01': '0.705', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.698'}),
 (7, {'A01': '0.704', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.697'}),
 (8, {'A01': '0.703', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.697'}),
 (9, {'A01': '0.703', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.696'}),
 (10, {'A01': '0.702', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.696'}),
 (11, {'A01': '0.702', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.696'}),
 .
 .
 .
 (59, {'A01': '0.684', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.679'}),
 (60, {'A01': '0.683', 'A05': '0.114', 'B01': '0.678'})]
```

Finally, iterate over the dictionary (sorted by reading number) and output the abs values. The final output should look like this:

```
          A05       A01       B01
Reading   Abs       Abs       Abs
1         0.113     0.706     0.698
2         0.114     0.706     0.698
3         0.114     0.705     0.698
4         0.114     0.705     0.698
5         0.114     0.705     0.698
6         0.114     0.705     0.698
7         0.114     0.704     0.697
8         0.114     0.703     0.697
9         0.114     0.703     0.696
10        0.114     0.702     0.696
11        0.114     0.702     0.696
.
.
.
59        0.114     0.684     0.679
60        0.114     0.683     0.678
```